# Join File operation with awk

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, awk

I have a base file of 36 Million numbers with **SERIALNO** and **n** no of column and another file having less than or equal to 36 Million data with first common SERIALNO column like base file and **m** number of column , all data separated with coma.

I need to match basefile 1st column to file 1st column and output like serialnumber,column basefile:1,..,basefile:n, column file:1, .., column file:m and if basefile data is not available in file, need capture that values also.

I have tried join command and grep command as well but very slow to process huge file. any body can suggest any other alternative

I think awk is much faster for file operation.

**base file**

```
serialno1,a,b,c,d
serialno2,a1,b2,c2,d2
serialno3,a3,b3,c3,d3
```

**File**

```
serialno1,e,f,g,h
serialno2,e1,f2,g2,h2
serialno4,e4,f4,g4,h4
```

**Output Expected**

```
serialno1,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
serialno2,a1,b2,c2,d2,e1,f2,g2,h2
serialno3,a3,b3,c3,d3,,,,,
```

Comment: Is there some class handing out homework assignments right now? This is an exact dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/40905983/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

To remove non-repeated values from file2, use this:

```
awk -F ',' '{  if (NR==FNR){
                       r[$1]=$0
               }else{
                       if($1 in r){
                             r[$1]=r[$1]gensub($1,"",1)
                       }else{ 
                             r[$1]=r[$1] ",,,"
                       }
               }
             }END{
                       for(i in r){print r[i]}
             }' infile infile2  |
awk -F ',' 'a="";NF<8{a=",,,"}
            {printf("%s%s%s",$0,a,RS)}'
```

Note the `|` character, that sends the result to the second awk command.

Comment: Hi Dude, its working but one problem like i am getting serialno4,e4,f4,g4,h4 also in output , i dont want any value not in the basefile. its like left out join ---> A-B+ AUB

Comment: Thanks dude, its perfectly working , I need one more help can you do, file 2 having fixed column number like m. that much filed can be add in output serialno3,a3,b3,c3,d3,,,, simple comma separeted or dummy value

Comment: @ArunBinoy Request added.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    FNR==NR{d[$1]=substr($0,index($0,",")+1); next}
    {print $0, ($1 in d?d[$1]:",,,,")}' file base_file
```

you get,

```
serialno1,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
serialno2,a1,b2,c2,d2,e1,f2,g2,h2
serialno3,a3,b3,c3,d3,,,,,
```